# how to solve this error "set the EnableWindowsTargeting property to true." NETSDK1100

Tags: asp.net-core, sdk, .net-8.0

I don't know what am stuck at, but it's brevetting me from doing something.
searched for it looks like it's a new thing, couldn't found anything.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(90,5): error NETSDK1100: To build a project targeting Windows on this operating system, set the EnableWindowsTargeting property to true. [/sec/root/****/*****.Native.csproj]

so i tried to do what they told me...
`cat /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets | grep -C 2 EnableWindowsTargeting`

and this was the output:

```
EnableTargetingPackDownload="$(EnableTargetingPackDownload)"
                                EnableRuntimePackDownload="$(EnableRuntimePackDownload)"
                                EnableWindowsTargeting="$(EnableWindowsTargeting)"
                                DisableTransitiveFrameworkReferenceDownloads="$(DisableTransitiveFrameworkReferenceDownloads)"
                                KnownCrossgen2Packs="@(KnownCrossgen2Pack)"
```

now where should I put the **true**
it should've been looked like this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnableWindowsTargeting>true</EnableWindowsTargeting>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

> error NETSDK1100: To build a project targeting Windows on this
> operating system, set the EnableWindowsTargeting property to true.

`NetSDK1100` indicates that you're building a project that targets Windows on Linux or macOS. By default, .NET downloads all targeting packages but target and runtime packages are not automatically downloaded on unsupported platforms. These can be wrapped in cross-target downloads by setting the EnableWindowsTargeting property. You can set it in the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnableWindowsTargeting>true</EnableWindowsTargeting>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Or by passing /p:EnableWindowsTargeting=true to a .NET CLI command, such as dotnet build. If you want to apply this setting to your whole solution or repository, you can set it in a Directory.Build.props file.